# How would I describe "extra" (unprompted, extracurricular) work I did for an employer that was of benefit to a company on my resume?

Tags: resume

In my current job I authored and maintain a tool that is used organization wide and saves several hundred man hours a year. Unfortunately since it has proprietary logic I can't host it on git, but I'd love to mention it on my resume. Thing is, I built in my spare time, a coffee break hear, waiting for a windows update there.

I'm quite proud of it, and really think that it is one of my better achievements with the company -- how would I list it on my resume?

Comment: *I authored and maintain a tool that is used organization wide and saves several hundred man hours a year.* That's a good start right there.

Comment: Like you would anything else you did at work

Comment: Your question seems to make it clear you believe the fact you created this on your own initiative is relevant when it comes to putting it on a resume. But why? Do you think it's somehow less valuable? Or that it's actually more valuable and you want to use this to showcase how you like to take initiative and improve existing processes?

Comment: Note that depending upon jurisdiction, unpaid overtime can lead to legal actions against the company authorized or not and the decision as to whether it will or won’t isn’t yours to make.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to put it on git.

Write a sentence or two that covers what it did, how it was used, how much money/time it saved and that fact that you took the initiative to design, develop, and maintain the software.

It highlights that you take initiative to create useful things.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm quite proud of it, and really think that it is one of my better
>   achievements with the company -- how would I list it on my resume?

Something like "I authored and maintain a tool that is used organization wide and saves several hundred man hours a year." would work.

It would likely prompt some interview questions that you can be ready to answer:

- Tell me about this tool.
- Whose idea was it?
- How long did it take to build?
- How do you know how many hours it saves?
- etc.